# Redirecting user to native camera and not canvas preview

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I'm new to c#/windows phone SDK and I did search a lot for a simple redirect to native camera control of Windows Phone 8.

Examples that I found speak of creating a canvas and receive a live preview of camera, which I don't want.

I would like to know how to redirect user to camera, like WhatsApp and Facebook does.

I know that for connection settings, for example, this code would redirect to WiFi network. Is there any Task like that, to camera?

```
ConnectionSettingsTask connectionSettingsTask = new ConnectionSettingsTask();
connectionSettingsTask.ConnectionSettingsType = ConnectionSettingsType.WiFi;
connectionSettingsTask.Show();
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

As you found out yourself you can use the `CameraCaptureTask`, another way is to allow the user to either choose a picture from their albums OR take a new picture, which can be done with the following code, which also allows you to set a specific size of the returned image:

```
Microsoft.Phone.Tasks.PhotoChooserTask task = new Microsoft.Phone.Tasks.PhotoChooserTask();
task.ShowCamera = true;
task.PixelWidth = 100;
task.PixelHeight = 100;
task.Completed += task_Completed;
task.Show();
```

This can be helpful if you don't want to write extra code for cropping the image to a chosen size :)

Comment: A good reference for all tasks is this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.tasks(v=vs.105).aspx :)

Answer (score 0):

Some more search time and I found [this tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh394006%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) at [Windows Phone Dev Center](http://dev.windowsphone.com/en-us/):

```
using Microsoft.Phone.Tasks;

CameraCaptureTask cameraCaptureTask = new CameraCaptureTask();
cameraCaptureTask.Show();
```

Which was exactly what I was searching. The tutorial also specify a code to retrieve the just taken picture and show it as image control.